# How to create a loop from 1-9 and from a-z?

Tags: python

I currently use:

```
for i in range(1,10):
   print i
```

Which prints the digits 1 to 9. But I want to add a-z to the mix. How can I combine them?

Comment: You can create an alphabet array. And read array in while loop.

Comment: `import string`, then `for character in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits: print character`.

Comment: @Apero Maybe he's been asking good questions, possibly on totally different type of topics. You shouldn't judge someone entirely based on their reputation points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
for i in range(1,10) + [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]:
    print i
```

It prints 1 through 9 followed by a through z.

Comment: `[chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]` is a rather verbose way of spelling `list(string.ascii_lowercase)`..

Comment: Yes, I like your answer better. I don't know why mine was accepted.

Comment: That's life, sometimes the OP makes a different choice.

Comment: @JosephBisch. Maybe it's because you got it all on one line ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Rather than create a range, loop over a *string*, to get individual characters:

```
import string

for character in string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits[1:]:
    print character
```

This uses the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to grab pre-defined strings of ASCII lowercase letters and digits.

The `string.digits[1:]` slice removes the `'0'` character to leave just the digits `'1'` through to `'9'`.

Comment: @Tom: slice the string `string.digits[1:]`, or define your own `+ '123456789'`.

Answer (score 0):

Generate it using list compression and chr() and ord() functions in python;

```
character = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
```

similarly for the numbers:

```
numbers = [i for i in range(0, 10)]
```

ord() is used to get the ASCII values of character and chr() is used to get the string using ASCII.