# Write a test program that prints ten characters per line from 1 to Z

Tags: python, function

Write a function that prints characters using the following header:
`def printChars(ch1, ch2, numberPerLine)`:
This function prints the characters between `ch1` and `ch2` with the specified numbers per line.
I want to write a test program that prints ten characters per line from 1 to Z.

```
def main():
    printCenter code herehars("1","Z",10)

def printChars(ch1,ch2,numberPerLine):
    for i in range(ord(ch1), ord(ch2) + 1):
        print(chr(i), end='')
        if (i - ord(ch1)) % numberPerLine == numberPerLine - 1:
            print()

main()
```

The output:

```
123456789:
;<=>?@ABCD
EFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWX
YZ
```

The program is supposed to print :

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a loop from 1-9 and from a-z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799607/how-to-create-a-loop-from-1-9-and-from-a-z)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
>>> import string
>>> alpha_caps = string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase
>>> alpha_caps_res = ' '.join(alpha_caps[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(alpha_caps), 10))
>>> alpha_caps_res
'0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJ KLMNOPQRST UVWXYZ'
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to first construct your available output `chars`, either create the string manually or take the values from [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string.digits#string.digits). Next use string indexing to determine where in the string your `ch1` and `ch2` characters exist. With this you can then slice the string to give you all the characters you need. Lastly use `range()` from `0` to the length of `output`. The last parameter tells it to skip `numberPerLine` values. This then gives you the starting indexes for each line of your print.

```
import string

def printChars(ch1, ch2, numberPerLine):
    chars = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase  # Same as doing 0123456789A......Z
    output = chars[chars.index(ch1):chars.index(ch2)+1]

    for start in range(0, len(output), numberPerLine):
        print(output[start:start+numberPerLine])

printChars("0", "Z", 10)
```

Giving you:

```
0123456789
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
def main():
    printCenter code herehars("1","Z",10)

def printChars(ch1,ch2,numberPerLine):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(ord(ch1), ord(ch2) + 1):
        if chr(i).isalnum():
            print(chr(i), end='')
            counter++
        if counter % numberPerLine == numberPerLine - 1:
            print()

main()
```